# How to write unit test for controller in spring boot

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I am new to Unit testing and TDD. I want to apply unit testing for my controller and service class which i have written in spring boot.

I have implemented test class using a tutorial. However, I could not implemented it successfully. I have included my current code.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, 
        @RequestBody User user){
        ResponseDTO finalResponse = new ResponseDTO();
        try {
            ResponseEntity<?> entity = myService.create(token, user);             
            finalResponse.setMessageCode(entity.getStatusCode());
            finalResponse.setMessage("Success");
            finalResponse.setError(false);
            ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().body(finalResponse);
        return finalEntity;
        } catch (Exception e) {      
            finalResponse.setMessageCode(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
            finalResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            finalResponse.setError(true);
            ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = 
            ResponseEntity.ok().body(finalResponse);
            return finalEntity;
    }
}
```

**ResponseDTO**

```
public class ResponseDTO {
    private HttpStatus messageCode;
    private String message;
    private String messageDetail;
    private Object body;
    private boolean error;

    //setters and getters
}
```

**Current Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/create")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
    }

}
```

When i run test class i am getting `WARN Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'Authorization' for method parameter of type String]`

What am i doing wrong here? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: You missed `.header("Authorization", "some value")` for your mockMvc. BTW, `.content("your testing payload")` is also missed.

Comment: It's not unit test if you are writing a test for controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test could be something like this:

```
 @Test
public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/create")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("AUTH_TOKEN", TOKEN)
        .content(ObjectToJsonUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(user)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
}
```

you'll have to convert object user to json.
So you create a util class for this:

```
public class ObjectToJsonUtil {
    public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i use mock token?

Comment: There is a spring annotation that mocks your security context. Annotate your test with: @WithMockUser(username = "myUser", roles = { "myAuthority" })

Comment: I got error in `.content(user))` which says, The method content(byte[]) in the type MockHttpServletRequestBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (User)

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to convert object user to json using an util class. What do you do with the authorization token in your service? Just to check if validation is needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your test:

#### 1. Request mapping

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(
    @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token, 
    @RequestBody User user)
```

only matches `POST` requests that have an HTTP header named `Authorization` and a request body that can be serialized to `User`. These are not optional. If they are optional, you should explicitly declare that:

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(
   @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization", required = false) String token, 
   @RequestBody(required = false) User user) {
```

Assuming that they are required, you should setup MockMvc to send both to your controller:

```java
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/create")
                  .header("Authorization", "XYZ")
                  .content("{\"firstName\": \"James\", \"lastName\": \"Gosling\"}")
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
               .andExpect(status().isCreated())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
    }
```

here I have assumed your `User` class is like this:

```java
public class User {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

#### 2. `Content-Type` header

Also, you should set the content type header for your MockMvc request, otherwise the test will fail with `415 - Unsupported Media Type`. So your test should look like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/create")
                  .header("Authorization", "XYZ")
                  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                  .content("{\"firstName\": \"James\", \"lastName\": \"Gosling\"}")
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
               .andExpect(status().isCreated())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
    }
```

#### 3. Mocked dependencies

Apart from that, in your test you have annotated `MyController` with `@InjectMocks` but you haven't mocked its `MyService' dependency. That will set the`myService`field of your controller to`null`. To fix that you need to mock`MyService' too:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // Mock
    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        // Configure mock myService
        when(myService.create(anyString(), any(User.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED));

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/create")
                  .header("Authorization", "XYZ")
                  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                  .content("{\"firstName\": \"James\", \"lastName\": \"Gosling\"}")
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
               .andExpect(status().isCreated())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
    }

}
```

#### 4. `MyService` does not satisfy the test conditions

When everything is hunky dory your controller responds with:

```java
ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().body(finalResponse);
```

which will return a status code of 200. So you either have to modify your test to expect that:

```java
.andExpect(status().isOk())
```

or you should update your controller to return with the 201 status code:

```java
ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> finalEntity = ResponseEntity.created(null).body(finalResponse);
```